# Android: Программный сброс входящего звонка

Tags: java, android

Приложение сбрасывает входящий звонок и сохраняет номер звонящего.
Все нормально работало, но появилась проблема на Samsung j3 (Android 7.0), логирование происходит (в приложенном коде убрал его), а звонок не сбрасывается.

В чем может быть проблема?

Пермишены:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Класс, который должен сбрасывать звонок:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements ITelephony {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
            String phoneState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (phoneState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                ITelephony telephonyService;
                TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
                        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                try {
                    Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
                    if (telephonyService != null)
                        telephonyService.endCall();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean endCall() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void answerRingingCall() {
    }

    @Override
    public void silenceRinger() {
    }

}
```

P.S. У меня нет устройства, на котором проблема воспроизводится, на моих девайсах все работает.

UPD: 
Я изучаю проблему на англоязычном SO, нашел человека с похожей проблемой. Опять же догадка, ибо о проблеме мне сообщил юзер, а у меня нет устройств Самсунг. 
В его случае при таком же методе сброса звонка возникает ошибка, что нужен пермишен `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE`, который есть только у системных приложений.
В таком случае я не понимаю, почему на устройствах OnePlus 6 и Xiaomi Mi Max 3 с Android 9.0 и Xiaomi Mi Max 2 с Android 8.0 приложение работает без этого пермишена, а на Samsung j3 со "старым" Android 7.0 возникает такая проблема? Как в таком случае на нем работают "черные списки" с Google Play и т.д.? Буду рад любым подсказкам по этой теме.

Comment: Оболочки разных производителей немного меняют систему, как следствие иногда надо быть готовым к таким проблемам, как пример intent при перезагрузке устройства

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приложенный способ не удалось заставить работать на Samsung-устройствах. 
Как подметили в комментариях, производители часто немного меняют систему, а способ с `ITelephony` скорее хак, чем нормальное решение, поэтому его неработоспособность на Samsung вполне нормальное явление. Проблема действительно была в пермишене `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE`, который никак нельзя получить.

Есть рабочее решение для Android 6.0+. Приложение должно заменить стандартное приложение для звонков (default call dialer). Это делается довольно просто, в итоге Android сам будет передавать звонки приложению, а там уже можно их сбрасывать. Прикладываю код на `kotlin`.

В первую очередь в манифест нужно добавить `intent filters` в `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
</intent-filter>
```

и добавить сервис для обработки звонков

```
<service
    android:name=".CallService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INCALL_SERVICE">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.telecom.IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI"
        android:value="true"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.InCallService" />
            </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Так же при запуске приложения нужно убедиться, что оно установлено как стандартное для звонков и в случае необходимости сделать себя текущим приложением для звонков:

```
if (getSystemService(TelecomManager::class.java).defaultDialerPackage != packageName) {
    Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER)
            .putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName)
            .let(::startActivity)
}
```

Код сервиса:

```
class CallService : InCallService() {

    override fun onCallAdded(call: Call) {
        OngoingCall.call = call
        val number = call.details.handle.schemeSpecificPart // номер телефона
        // тут можно логировать и вообще что угодно
        OngoingCall.hangup() // сбросить вызов
    }

    override fun onCallRemoved(call: Call) {
        OngoingCall.call = null
    }

}
```

В целом эта тема достаточно хорошо раскрыта, есть статьи, например:

[Android default dialer replacement (part I)](https://medium.com/makingtuenti/android-default-dialer-replacement-part-i-722d05ca50fe)

[Android default dialer replacement (part II)](https://medium.com/makingtuenti/android-default-dialer-replacement-part-ii-48aa4328594d)